# How to cluster a massive amount of data that doesn't fit into memory?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, cluster-analysis, data-analysis

I have 30 files, each is a dictionary with about 1M keys that map to embeddings:

```
file_1 = {key_1: some_array, key_2: some_array ...} 
file_2 = {key_13: some_array, key_21: some_array ...} 
... 
file_30 = {key_123: some_array, key_9: some_array ...}
```

Normally I would just use [KMeans](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) on the embeddings, but the issue is that I can't load all of them into memory. This brings out several issues:

1. I'm not sure how to find how many clusters are optimal.
2. Once I know how many clusters, I'm not entirely sure how to find the cluster centers.
3. I don't know if KMeans is the right approach for this or if there's a more efficient way to do this.

I can load about 10M of them, which I think is a sufficient sample size, and then maybe find the clusters based on these (or even a smaller sample size), but not sure if that's the right approach or if there's something better. I'm also not entirely sure that I can do any sort of computation on 10M samples -- I can load them, but anything else might exceed my memory.

Comment: 10M+ is also a bit expensive for typical KMeans implementations. I'd be inclined to use MiniBatch KMeans or similar, at least as an initialization. The engineer in me says rent a bigger machine (1TB of RAM is cheap to borrow for an hour) and be done with it. If you're stuck using Python on a small machine it's not too terrible to back numpy arrays with memory mapped files (map them as "shared" to ensure the OS can swap pages back out), and you could operate that way. Doing so is easier if you're writing it from scratch if the scipy KMeans does too much allocation.

Comment: As to selecting cluster counts and whether it's the right approach, that depends on why you're clustering and is a much more involved question that needs more context. Here's a link that might be helpful for selecting cluster counts https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_silhouette_analysis.html

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution to find how many clusters is optimal. The graphic ways are optimized for tons of data. The way i found to solve this problem is using eigen vectors and eigen values.

I use R so the solution this one is only i tested but in python it can work the same way.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import eigh

cov_matrix = np.cov(df.T)  # Transpose of df to get observations as rows
values, vectors = eigh(cov_matrix)
count = np.sum(values > 1)
print(count)
```